# OSX : Shell : Extract data from XML and overwrite original file

Tags: xml, macos, file, split

Im trying to optimize a workflow from another app im using. The app extracts XML from a file, from there it will upload that XML onto a designated server. However, the XML only have a few useful information (usually the first 5kbs, from a 10-20mb XML). Im trying to create a script to open the xml or split it, then take the useful 5kb of data and overwrite the original XML. So far, I haven't had much luck doing so. Can someone give me some help.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far in a little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an XSLT file to extract what you need and call the `xsltproc` command to apply it against your big XML file.

However, since you application produces that XML file in the first place, why not produce a minimal version for upload to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/private/var/root/Documents/XML/*.xml
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  split -b 20000 "$f" tmp
  mv tmpaa "$f"
  rm tmp*
done
```